# German Special characters like "Ü" in File path and File name - unable to use path as string

Tags: python

I am using Python to split PDFs based on a certain logic.

I came across an error today. If there are special characters like "Ü" in file path or file name my code fails as I'm using file path as string. And the character "Ü" is converted to "�".

I'm using following code to extract file name.

```
pp = ntpath.basename(pdff) #"pdff is ths file path that I am passing as string"
```

I am literally editing and pasting the file path into a string using

```
pdff = "C\filepath\Über.pdf"
```

And when I print pdff the path changes to "C\filepath\�ber.pdf"

I am working on Windows with Python 3.7.

Please suggest a solution to retain the special characters in the string.

Comment: Python's filename/path handling plays perfectly nice with Unicode, *especially* on Windows where file names are internally Unicode strings and not bytes like on *nix. Whatever's mangling your strings, I don't think it's the path handling functions.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of the problem!

Comment: Windows has no problem with Unicode. Windows *IS UNICODE* natively. NTFS is Unicde. In fact, `�` is a *Unicode* character used when trying to read **non-Unicode** text using the wrong codepage

Comment: How is the file name stored on your disk? Is it stored as unicode or is it maybe stored using iso-latin-1 encoding? You may have to tell Python explicitly what the encoding of the filename is.

Comment: Where did `pdff` come from? To get `�` it must have come from a non-Unicode source, eg a file stored using a specific single-byte codepage?

Comment: @DanielJunglas Windows paths are Unicode, or rather, NTFS, exFAT and FAT32 paths are Unicode. Windows is Unicode, so to get a non-Unicode path an application has to explicitly use a non-Unicode API

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't work a lot on Windows, but I am pretty sure that when I create a file using C's `fopen()` function and pass an iso-latin-1 filename then this did not get transcoded to unicode. At least that is what I remember from a few years back.

Comment: @DanielJunglas that's the bug I was talking about. Since 1994, the Windows NT line is Unicode from the start. Strings in Windows are UTF16. If you use an ASCII API though , you're using the system default locale's codepage, whose description is `the codepage used by non-Unicode applications`. There's no reason to use non-Unicode APIs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, not sure whether this is a bug or not. My point in my original comment was that the name on the disk may not be in unicode (for whatever reason) and you may have to explicitly transcode it. IMO it is at least worth checking what the exact characters are you get back from the OS.

Comment: @DanielJunglas that's not possible in any of the "modern" file systems, which *are* Unicode (ie NTFS, FAT32 and later). The file path gets mangled by the application, not the OS. This isn't a transcoding issue - the file name is already bad, or in the case of the replacement characters `?` or `�` lost before it even reached the disk

Comment: @DanielJunglas `when I create a file using C's fopen()` unless you use `char16_t` or `char8_t` you're using ASCII strings with `fopen`. Which shouldn't be done.